# How to TEXTJOIN/CONCATENATE based on constraints for specific no of rows count

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, concatenation

I need to concatenate certain attribute value based on the sequence number for specific material number and a formula to automate the process.
I have columns as listed in the below screen shot and I want to get my result as in "Expected Result" column.
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmMoP.png)

What are all the helper columns I need and how to get my expected values by formula?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of Excel, you can try and adapt the following formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTER(FILTER($A$1:$F$14,$A$1:$A$14=A1),{0,0,0,1,1,1})),"RAM","RAM:")," ROM",", ROM:")," Screen size",", Screen size:")," Thickness",", Thickness:")," Certification", ", Certification:")
```

Drag the formula down to fill the other cells.

**Explanation:**

- `FILTER($A$1:$F$14,$A$1:$A$14=A1)`: filters the data based on the first column value (Material number).
- `FILTER(FILTER($A$1:$F$14,$A$1:$A$14=A1),{0,0,0,1,1,1}))`: the result of the inner/previous formula is filtered to return only the attributes' names, values and units of measurement.
- `TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTER(FILTER($A$1:$F$14,$A$1:$A$14=A1),{0,0,0,1,1,1}))`: the previous formula's results are joined by a space.
- Finally, some words are replaced to added commas and semi-colons.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The same idea, but a slightly different formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN({": "," ",", "},TRUE,
FILTER($D$2:$F$22,$A$2:$A$22=$A2))," CERTIFICATION", "",2),
": CERTIFICATION",",")
```

[image: List]