How to TEXTJOIN specific no of rows based on constraints?
I need to concatenate certain attribute value based on the sequence number for specific material number and a formula to automate the process. I have columns as listed in the below screen shot and I want to get my result as in "Expected Result" column.  Expected Result
What are all the helper columns I need and how to get my expected values by formula?
Some complex Example available in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UohDcgBMZThzG37s0nDpRYbFFRNGeCeV/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=100858153522202375139&rtpof=true&sd=true

You should strive to make your question self-contained. As it is, when the link to the google sheet goes dead, your question will become incomprehensible.

Also why is the CERTIFICATION sorted in no proper order, what is the order you have maintained for CERTIFICATION and STANDARD ?

You could try using the following formula: =LET(a, FILTER($D$2:$F$31, $A$2:$A$31=A2,""),b, TAKE(a,,1),c, UNIQUE(b),TEXTJOIN({": ",", "},,HSTACK(c, MAP(c,LAMBDA(m, TEXTJOIN({", ",", ",", "},1,TRIM(FILTER(INDEX(a,,2)&" "&INDEX(a,,3),b=m)))))))) however clarification needed for the above comment of mine

And this is the same question asked earlier : here

Does this answer your question? How to TEXTJOIN/CONCATENATE based on constraints for specific no of rows count

@MayukhBhattacharya. You are a genius man.!!! I have made a mistake in the expected result in the google doc. But your formula is giving the correct expected result. Thanks a lot. By the way, I just want to know from where I can learn this kind of complex formulae and methods? Any useful resource pages?

Do you want me to post the same as an answer? Learning, I dont know when I started but obviously helped me by following answers from Experts in StackOverflow , SuperUser and CodeGolf one of the person commented above @EngineerToast Sir , could follow his solutions, will help you learn as well.

Yes, it solves my requirement. You can post this as answer.

@MayukhBhattacharya Yes, it solves my requirement. You can post this as answer. Yes, I have asked the same question earlier here https://superuser.com/q/1822951/1247873. but the answers provided has not resolved my query. Now how can I mark you comment as the solution?

As mentioned above in comments, and the given formula has worked, OP has also clarified about the doubts as well:


• Formula used in cell G2
=LET(
     α, FILTER($D$2:$F$31, $A$2:$A$31=A2,""),
     δ, TAKE(α,,1),
     φ, UNIQUE(δ),
     TEXTJOIN({": ",", "},,HSTACK(φ, MAP(φ,LAMBDA(m, 
     TEXTJOIN({", ",", ",", "},1,TRIM(FILTER(INDEX(α,,2)&" "&INDEX(α,,3),δ=m))))))))


NOTE: The above formula needs to be filled down for rest of the cells

Updated Formula:
=LET(
     α, FILTER($D$2:$F$31, $A$2:$A$31=A2,""),
     δ, TAKE(α,,1),
     φ, UNIQUE(δ),
     ε, INDEX(α,,2),
     ∞, INDEX(α,,3),
     TEXTJOIN({": ",", "},1,HSTACK(φ, MAP(φ,LAMBDA(m,
     TEXTJOIN({", ",", ",", "},1,TRIM(FILTER(ε&" "&IF(ε="","-",TEXT(∞,"General;;")),δ=m))))))))



I have a new requirement now that if one attribute is blank ex: POLE QUANTITY then it has to give value with Hyphen (-) as following "DESIGN TYPE: AC-6B, CURRENT RATING: 84 A, VOLTAGE RATING: 690 V, CONTACT TYPE: 3NO, MOUNTING DETAILS: DIN RAIL, SCREW, FREQUENCY RATING: 50/60 HZ, POLE QUANTITY: -, CERTIFICATION: CCC CERTIFIED, CE CERTIFIED, CSA CERTIFIED, ROHS COMPLIANT, UL LISTED, AUXILIARY CONTACT VOLTAGE: 230 VAC" What modification required in the formula to do so?

Can you please look into the above?

@VigneshK updated!

Is it only work for POLE QUANTITY alone? If any of the attribute is blank the expected result is to come - "Hypen" in that place; POLE QUANTITY is one such example, it can be any values available in "D" column.

Can you please look in to the above request?

@VigneshK formula updated see the second formula!

No, the formula is not working if I blank the value for DESIGN TYPE attribute; It has to give as  "DESING TYPE: - ", but it is not. It works only if I blank the value for POLE QUANTITY

@VigneshK download the excel from here and check please

Working fine. Thanks a lot. So the final formula is
=LET(
α, FILTER($D:$F, $A:$A=A2,""),
δ, TAKE(α,,1),
φ, UNIQUE(δ),
ε, INDEX(α,,2),
∞, INDEX(α,,3),
TEXTJOIN({": ",", "},1,HSTACK(φ, MAP(φ,LAMBDA(m,
TEXTJOIN({", ",", ",", "},1,TRIM(FILTER(ε&" "&IF(ε="","-",TEXT(∞,"General;;")),δ=m))))))))

I have a question here. Why the CERTIFICATION attribute values are alphabetically getting sorted instead of concatenating as it is? Ex:  If the order avl in excel is CSA, UL, CCC, IEC your formula is giving result as CCC, CSA, IEC, UL instead of CSA, UL, CCC IEC.
Also now, the new requirement is instead of concatenating as "CSA, UL, CCC, IEC" it now required to concatenate as following "CSA, UL CCC IEC" (i.e without comma separation after second value) can u pls help me?

@VigneshK one question per post. You are asking too many questions in one post. It is not sorting please try to evaluate the formula, SORT() function is not used here

Sorry mate. Since the result I got is getting sorted asked. No issue. thanks for this extended support!!

@VigneshK already if there is no rush comment the file link i will check it. please highlight the area.

I have a new requirement, Is it possible to generate the same expected result, even if the UNSPSC attributes are jumbled (i.e Material row is not continuous by same number, it is jumbled). In this case it has to use the 'Sequence of attributes" 1,2,3,4 for generating the same result even these are not sorted and available next to each other. I have posted the jumbled and expected result example in this link sheet name "Jumbled"
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UohDcgBMZThzG37s0nDpRYbFFRNGeCeV/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100858153522202375139&rtpof=true&sd=true
